# regex to add spaces in specific places

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a 14 digits long number that I need to split into this format:

```
xxx xxx xxx xxxxx
```

I have a regex that splits every 3 characters starting from the end (because of the lookahead?)

```
(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

Which gives me:

```
xx xxx xxx xxx xxx
```

I tried using lookbehind in regex101.com but I get a pattern error...

```
(?<=(\d{3})+(?!\d))
```

How can I use lookbehind so that it starts from the begining of the string (if that's my issue) and how can I repeat the pattern only 3 times and then switch to a `\d{5}` ?

Comment: The best answer may be 'do not use regex for this'... A simple for-loop is probably much easier.

Comment: you can try this regex to check the final result https://regex101.com/r/3dltJm/4/ `(^\+|\d{3} |\d{5}$)`

Comment: *"How can I use lookbehind so that it starts from the begining of the string*" -I don't think JavaScript Regex has the look behind feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})
```

and replace by this:

```
"$1 $2 $3 "
```

[Regex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/YB9DUd/2/)

```js
const regex = /(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{3})/g;
const str = `12345678901234`;
const subst = `$1 $2 $3 `;
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);
console.log( result);
```

Comment: I looked into it too much it seems and forgot about substitution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like so: https://regex101.com/r/yqmyvs/3

The regex for this being:

```
(?:\d{3})(?:\d{2}$)?
```

This basically says: I want groups of three numbers, unless it's the end of the string in which case I want 5.

Though, as commented on your question, this isn't really something you would normally use regex for.

Comment: I suggest to use /([\d]{3}(?:\d{2}$)?)/. In my Test-Script preg_split() captured "34" at the End too. Thats why I added the ?: in the last Subpattern, so it does not get put in the Split-array.

Comment: @Bernhard I already updated it to stop using capture groups since they aren't actually used

Comment: I cannot make this work for my needs. It does select the right groups but how do you insert spaces between them? (and no, a for loop is definitely not the right way to do this)

Comment: You get all of the matches and then just join them with a space?